# Naming the Push Notifications Permissions

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm trying to connect Parse to my app and it's working. The only problem is when the Push Notifications Permissions alert comes up my app is referred to as "null". If anyone could tell me that where I can change that. I'm using Xcode 7.2

Comment: could you be a little more specific in your question? when you allow the notifications does it come up null? or does the alert say "null"?

Comment: the alert says "null"

Comment: could you add the section of code that deals with your problem? and a picture of the issue?